# Changing the path of models into a models directory

Tags: php, laravel

**What I've done**
I used the command `php artisan make:model User` without mentioning model folder as the command should have been `php artisan make:model Models\User`.

I am an amateur in terms of laravel and just started php and laravel last month and made a whole multi vendor project around it without the models being in models folder.

**What I want**
Now, I'm just trying to structure my code in a cleaner manner and facing errors as have to change the path of models wherever it is mentioned. I tried doing them but still can't get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Laravel, by default, file is already created inside the Models folder. If you have a model outside folder and what you want is to incorporate it there, the best thing to do is to change the built-in namespace at the top of everything. For example:

`namespace App\Models;`

If you want is to completely change the path, first create the model and then move folder manually. Finally, in namespace mention it:

`namespace FolderA\FolderB\FolderC;`.

Although it is always better to follow the default Laravel structure, is cleaner.

Comment: i did change the path after i moved the files manually in model folder but i faced an error something related to vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your
Project/config/auth.php
file on
'model'=> AppName\Models\User::class,

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to move 1 model at a time and replace all of its import namespaces. Test your application if everything works and then continue with the next model and so on.

Example:

1. Move User.php from `App\` to `App\Models` folder
2. Update the namespace of `User.php` from `namespace App;` to `namespace App\Models;`
3. Find and replace in your project (global search) for: `use App\User.php` and replace all results with `use App\Models\User.php`
4. Check your application and run tests if you have them.
5. If everything is ok, you can continue moving the next model to the Model/ folder and repeat step 1 to 5

For the model User.php: As @saeed mentioned, update your `config/auth.php` if needed.

Note that IDE's these days can do the most work for you, like PhpStorm can do all the find & replaces for you when you pressing F6 on the User.php file in the tree and update its path.